# Convert a number with comma and letter to a float?

Tags: python-3.x

In my web scraping I get the price as: 524,00 kr
Now I want to remove whatever is after comma. It should give me 524. Here is my code:

```
price = soup.find (class_ ='..............').get_text() 
price = re.sub("$", "", "524,00 kr")
converted_price = float.fromhex(price2[0:4])
if(converted_price < 1000):
send_mail()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a regex, use the `str.split` function:

```
price = price.split(",")[0]
```

This splits the string at commas and then takes the first part.